# Ferromagnet : $N$ Spin-$1/2$ Particle on Circle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, ising-model, ferromagnetism

Consider one-dimensional ferromagnet namely $N$ spin-$1/2$ objects placed around a circle with the Hamiltonian
$$\mathscr{H}=-\mathcal{J}\sum_{n=1}^N\vec{\mathcal{S}}_n\cdot \vec{\mathcal{S}}_{n+1}$$
where we assume the periodic boundary condition $\vec{\mathcal{S}}_{N+1}\equiv \vec{\mathcal{S}}_1$ and $\mathcal{J}>0$.

I'm trying to show that total spin ket is a good quantum number that is they commute with $\mathscr{H}$ and finding out the energy corresponding to
$$|\psi_0\rangle =|\uparrow\rangle _1\otimes |\uparrow \rangle_2\otimes \cdots\otimes |\uparrow \rangle_N $$

By definition:
$$\mathcal{S}^2=\left(\sum_n \vec{\mathcal{S}}_n\right)^2=\sum_n \mathcal{S}_n^2+\sum_{i,j}\mathcal{\vec{S}}_i\cdot \mathcal{\vec{S}}_j$$
The second term has our Hamiltonian but there are other terms also. I don't understand, How do I proceed from here? Please help

Answer (score 1):

you should look at symmetries. The transformations that the total spin induces is a simultaneous rotations of all the spins. Such rotations leave the dot-product $\vec{S}_i \cdot \vec{S}_j$ unchanged. Therefore this is a symmetry of the system, which means that $\vec{S}_{\rm tot} = \sum_i \vec{S}_i$ are conserved, and represent good quantum numbers (of course one can only pick $S_{\rm tot}^2$ and one of the vector component, say $S_{\rm tot}^z$)

Comment: Yeah! I see that but How to show this?

Comment: just show that $\left[S^i_{\rm tot}, \vec{S}_n \cdot \vec{S}_m]\right]=0$ for all $i, n, m$. Most of the terms will be zero, and you would be left with $\left[S^{i}_n + S^{i}_m, \vec{S}_n \cdot \vec{S}_m \right]$ and from here it should be straight-forward

Comment: What's $S^i_\text{tot}$? Why there is a superscript? And I have to see the commutator for $S_\text{tot}^2$ and $H$.

Comment: by $S^i_{\rm tot}$ I mean the $i$-th component of the vector $\vec{S}_{\rm tot}$. So for example $S^x_{\rm tot} = \sum_n S^x_n$. If you can show that each component of the vector commutes individually with $H$, then naturally $S^2_{\rm tot} = \sum_i(S^i_{\rm tot})^2$ will also commute